AWS Lambda with ALB not able to download PDF using bottle API
I have a bottle API code deployed on Lambda and I am sending response back using make_lambda_handler from apig_wsgi. I am first using requests module downloading PDF content and then trying to attach the content as file in my response but I am getting utf-8 decoding error from apig_wsgi.
I  tried to base64 encode the data so that the apig_wsgi do not show error in that case the file is downloading but it says invalid file format. Although I see it is mentioned that ALB can handle binary data directly but since it was not working and showing decode error I tried the base64 encode as well. Is it because that apig_wsgi by default handle it for API Gateway . If yes what I should do to go around this problem. FYI - Same API when I am running on a conventional ubuntu server it is working successfully.
Download API code :
 def generate_document_invoice(self):
        # Retrieves the details of a specific invoice from Quickbooks Online by invoice ID.
        pdf_headers = self.headers.copy()
        pdf_headers['Accept'] = 'application/pdf'
        url = f"{self.base_url}/{self.provider_info['entity_id']}/invoice/{self.invoice_id}/pdf"
        invoice_response = requests.get(url, headers=pdf_headers, verify=False) 
        if invoice_response.status_code == 200:  
            download_response = bottle.HTTPResponse(body=invoice_response.content , status=200)
            download_response.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
            download_response.set_header('Content-Disposition', f'attachment; filename="invoice_{self.invoice_id}.pdf"')
            return download_response 
        return invoice_response.text

My WSGI lambda code
import bottle
import json

from functools import partial
from apig_wsgi import make_lambda_handler
from core import helper

from bottle import JSONPlugin

from .helper import *

json_plugin = JSONPlugin(json_dumps=partial(json.dumps, default=str))
app = bottle.default_app()
app.install(json_plugin)
# bottle.debug = True
service_lambda_handler = make_lambda_handler(app)

My Lambda Handler code:
`def lambda_handler(event, context):
     return service_lambda_handler(event, context)`

Download API code [WITH BASE 64 ENCODING]
 def generate_document_invoice(self):
        # Retrieves the details of a specific invoice from Quickbooks Online by invoice ID.
        pdf_headers = self.headers.copy()
        pdf_headers['Accept'] = 'application/pdf'
        url = f"{self.base_url}/{self.provider_info['entity_id']}/invoice/{self.invoice_id}/pdf"
        invoice_response = requests.get(url, headers=pdf_headers, verify=False) 
        base64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(invoice_response.content).decode('utf-8')
        if invoice_response.status_code == 200:
            # Set the response headers
    
            # # Set the response body to the base64 encoded PDF content
            # # Note that we're returning the base64 string, not the raw bytes
            download_response = bottle.HTTPResponse(body=base64_encoded_data , status=200)
            download_response.isBase64Encoded = True
            download_response.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
            download_response.set_header('Content-Disposition', f'attachment; filename="invoice_{self.invoice_id}.pdf"')
            return download_response 

I am short of ideas now and dont know what else can I try.
